# Translating excel formula to Javascript D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having a trouble to convert this formula to one I can use in d3.js based on the data below.

```
name    alpha        beta       max_x_val   spend
BAN1    140.3       3.86E-05    28,675.00   29,919.00
BAN2    115.31      2.08E-05    32,302.00   28,367.00
BAN3    5.07E-05    19,740.00   16,972.00
ADJ4    91.8        0.000029119 25,855.00   27,112.00
ADJ5    90.3        2.81E-05    25,793.00   23,883.00
```

I had initially translated this formula "y=Alpha(1-2.71828*(-Beta*x))" to the below code block but then the correct formula was to translate was the one below.

```
y=Alpha(1-2.71828^(-Beta*x))
```

SO how to change the below code block to accomadate this formula `'y=Alpha(1-2.71828^(-Beta*x))`'

```
var lineData = d3.range(0, jsonData.spend, 100)
                    .map(x => [ x, (jsonData.alpha * (1 - 2.71828*(-jsonData.beta * x)))/100] );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to change this:

```
y=Alpha(1-2.71828*(-Beta*x))
```

into this?

```
y=Alpha(1-2.71828^(-Beta*x))
```

You can use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) for exponential calculations:

```
var lineData = d3.range(0, jsonData.spend, 100)
                    .map(x => [x, (jsonData.alpha * (1 - Math.pow(2.71828, (-jsonData.beta * x))))/100] );
```